# Tweepy shows attribute error for search_tweets

Tags: python, tweepy

This is my code for extracting tweets

```
import tweepy
consumerKey = 'XXX'
consumerSecret = 'XXX'
accessToken = 'XXX'
accessTokenSecret = 'XXX'
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
auth = OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api=tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
k=api.search_tweets(q="iphone",lang="en")
```

It shows this error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-03a7c42af741> in <module>
      8 auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
      9 api=tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
---> 10 k=api.search_tweets("@iphone")

AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search_tweets'
```

Please help.

Comment: what version of tweepy do you have installed?

Comment: I am using google colab for this

Comment: Okay, but what version of the `tweepy` module are you using? try using `pip show tweepy`

Comment: It's Version: 4.10.0

Comment: Did you print the version from your notebook? When I create a new notebook and import tweepy, it imports version 3.10.0.